# Tools for debugging bitwise operations in Java

Tags: java, debugging, bitwise-operators

I have inherited a library that uses and abuses of bitwise operations. Up to now, I have developed a method that prints the bit representation of the variables that are used in such bitwise operations. Furthermore, the developed method can also be used to show the result of a particular bitwise operation in a set of variables.

However as the library code is quite extensive and these operations are used to handle the logic of the library, it would be great to have a debugging tool that could show the binary value of a variable or the result of a particular operation at runtime. This would avoid me to add many invocations of my method throughout the code in order to analyze what is happening in the code.

Does any one know such a tool that can help me debugging bitwise operations in Java?

P.S. Currently, I'm using Eclipse to debug the application but in the debugger the values are shown in a decimal representation.

Answer (score 5):

The Debug preferences for Java in Eclipse allow to select 'Display Hex Values'. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it does not help as I really need the binary representation to check the inputs and outputs of the bitwise operations.

Comment: Learning to quickly convert hex->binary in my head was the best thing I ever did to speed up debugging binary operations. Since each hex decimal is 4 binary decimals, it's a pretty simple conversion.

Comment: @Annie That seems interesting. Can you provide more info on how to do it?

Comment: Here is a good example: http://www.stringfunction.com/hex-binary.html
You can print out the chart of hex digit->binary and tape it to the side of your monitor while you're learning.

Answer (score 0):

You may always :

- put breakpoint within your code
- temporarly modify code while your are debugging - adding your method invokation
- selectiong with your mouse the part of the code that you have just written down
- pressing ctrl+shift+i to inspect the result
- once you get the result you may reverting your changes with ctrl+z

i.e. 
I have a code

1. int i = 1;
2. //do some stuff

I'm putting breakpoint in line 2 where 'i' var is already initialized
and while debugging I insert new line 2

1. int i = 1;
2. showBinaryRepresentation(i);
3. //do some stuff

now I select whole line 2 (with my on the fly code) and press ctrl+shift+i to see the result. Once I have it I may revert my modifications and proceed with debugging.